# ASP.NET MVC3 ActionResult Edit doesn't save changes in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, edit, viewbag

I have a problem with editing data in the controller. My two models look like this:

```
[Table("Zielgruppen")]
public class Zielgruppe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Zielgruppenname { get; set; }
    public Bezug Bezug { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Bezug
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bezugsname { get; set; }
}
```

The functions in my controller are:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Zielgruppe zielgruppe = _db.Zielgruppe.Include("Bezug").Single(z => z.Id == id);
    ViewBag.BezugsId = new SelectList(_db.Bezug, "Id", "Bezugsname", zielgruppe.Bezug.Id);
    return View(zielgruppe);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Zielgruppe aktualisierteZielgruppe)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        aktualisierteZielgruppe.Bezug = _db.Bezug.Find(aktualisierteZielgruppe.Bezug.Id);
        _db.Entry(aktualisierteZielgruppe).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.BezugsId = new SelectList(_db.Bezug, "Id", "Bezugsname", aktualisierteZielgruppe.Bezug.Id);
    return View();            
}
```

My Problem is that if i change aktualisierteZielgruppe.Bezug the changes won't get save in the database.

and this is my edit.cshtml:

```
@model Medien_Archiv.Models.Zielgruppe

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Zielgruppe</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zielgruppenname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zielgruppenname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zielgruppenname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bezug)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bezug.Id, ViewBag.BezugsId as SelectList)   
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the cases where entity framework falters - tracking updated associations.

I'm assuming that you're not doing any fancy model binding here (ie, model binder pulling from the database).

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    aktualisierteZielgruppe.Bezug = _db.Bezug.Find(aktualisierteZielgruppe.Bezug.Id);

    // The problem is here.  EF doesn't mark associations as modified
    // the same way it tracks scalar types.
    _db.Entry(aktualisierteZielgruppe).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here's the more conventional way:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    // Get the original record to edit from the database.
    var gruppe = _db.Zielgruppe.Include("Bezug").Single(z => z.Id == id);

    // This will attempt to do the model binding and map all the submitted 
    // properties to the attached entity.
    if (TryUpdateModel(grupppe))
    {
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Also note that this method of binding to entities leaves you [open to over-posting attacks.](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)  You can mitigate this attack vector by white-listing model properties during model binding, or bind against a view model and then map.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code, but it looks like you are loading the object from the database based on the id coming back from the view, setting it's State to Modified and then saving the same object.

It doesn't look like you're actually setting the properties from the view back to the object before saving it to the database. What ORM are you using? Most ORMs will handle the State of the object when each property is modified and essentially set its own state to Modified for when it's committed.

Set a breakpoint before you load your object from the database, quick watch the values coming back from the view and then quickwatch them again after you've loaded from the database, I think you'll discover you've overwritten them

Comment: ok my problem is that i obviously don't understand how `_db.Entry(aktualisierteZielgruppe).State = EntityState.Modified;` really works.  It only updates _Zielgruppenname_. Is there any other way to update data?

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing in a FormCollection like one of the examples above, you can modify its values and then reassign the FormCollection to the ValueProvider before you call TryUpdateModel(), like so:

```
this.ValueProvider = collection.ToValueProvider();
```

However, if you're passing in an Object, like a Zielgruppe, I don't know--trying to figure that one out myself.

Answer (score 0):

This was the first result from google so I'm leaving my comments here in case I can save some headache for someone else.

Here is what happened in my case. I have created my model and created all the necessary views with scaffolding. Then I have gone back and added a foreign key to my model.

While the index and edit view listed all the fields I nedded there was no value assigned to the foreign key. This resulted context.SaveChanges() to be never executed as the ModelState was invalid.

By pass the foreign key like below the issue was resolved.

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.*ForeignKey*)